# Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_kses()

Tags: php, wordpress

The error I am facing is:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_kses() in /home/izmhzpobft5b/public_html/wp-content/db.php:28 Stack trace:
#0 /home/izmhzpobft5b/public_html/wp-includes/load.php(671): require_once()
#1 /home/izmhzpobft5b/public_html/wp-settings.php(124): require_wp_db()
#2 /home/izmhzpobft5b/public_html/wp-config.php(95): require_once('/home/izmhzpobf...')
#3 /home/izmhzpobft5b/public_html/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home/izmhzpobf...')
#4 /home/izmhzpobft5b/public_html/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/home/izmhzpobf...')
#5 /home/izmhzpobft5b/public_html/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once('/home/izmhzpobf...')
#6 {main} thrown in /home/izmhzpobft5b/public_html/wp-content/db.php on line 28
```

I did these things:

1. Changed the plugin folder name.
2. Uploaded the fresh copy of Wordpress.

but no success.

Comment: Try disabling w3tc (w3 total cache) by **renaming** /wp-content/db.php to something else

Comment: @Ken Lee. I have deleted this plugin, still the issue is persistent.

Comment: Yes. Now the error is:
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

Please check that the mysqli PHP extension is installed and enabled.

.. 
Now there is MySQLi in phpinfo.php file's module. but there is no php.ini file.

Comment: Please check: phpinfo here:
https://alkhiardigitalmarketing.com/phpinfo.php

In Configure Command: --without-mysqli'

Comment: Please note that a mysql database is a must for WP to run. (and you need the appropriate extension(s) for PHP to use mysql)